# Trading View - How to trigger stop profit when the price rises above a certain price?

Tags: pine-script

everyone.

I'm new to pine and trying to set **taking profit in certain condition.**

-a- For instance, after current price is 10% higher than entry long price, stop profit is set to 5% higher from the entry long price.

So, if price come down to 5%, it will closed with 5% profit.
However, if price is still higher than 5%, it will ended until the strategy ends.

-b- Futhermore, if current price is higher than 20% of entry, I want to erase previous stop profit(-a-) condition and make the stop profit % as 10%.

I'm not sure this is possible in pinescript because I could not find the variable that return "current price"

I think someone has already thought the same thing as me, so if you know the reference address, please share it with me.

Please help me for long live the my account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The current price variable is close

> In the realtime bar, the close variable always represents the current price.

referring to pine script [manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#calculation-based-on-realtime-bars)